# Draw Image Function

Tags: image, canvas, draw

My friend and I are trying to add images to a canvas using JavaScript; however we have no clue how to even do that and we've tried every possible string of code involving drawing images (such as ones from google, etc), all with failure and we don't even know which direction is the right one to take at this point. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: This is kinda embarrassing but through some problem solving we figured it out...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of what you're seeking.

```js
document.getElementById('inp').onchange = function(e) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = draw;
  img.onerror = failed;
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
};
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
}
function failed() {
  console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Unless you're trying to develop a draw bot like function to parse each pixel from the image and draw it.